# How to render my image from Object.createUrl in my angular img tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, image

I have a file input and img tag in my angular component.

Here is the simple component html:

```
<input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" style="display: none;" id="fileInput" (change)="handleFileSelect($event)">
        <p-button (click)="openFileInput()" label="Add photo" styleClass="p-button-secondary" class="mr-3"></p-button> 

<img src="photo$.src" />
```

When i click the button it triggers the fileInput which does the handleFileSelect method

Here is my component:

```
 public handleFileSelect = (event: any) => {
    const selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    
    if (selectedFiles && selectedFiles.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
        const file = selectedFiles[i];
        this.photo$.src = URL.createObjectURL(file), 
      }
    }
  }
```

I get the url to be something like this:
blob:http://localhost:4300/c6db810c-4c3d-47d6-82c8-7adb630b369f

I copied and pasted this url in my browser and the image shows.
But somehow the img tag in my angular html cant pick it up.
I even placed the blob url directly in the img tag but it still doesnt render.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did u try <img [src]="photo$.src" />?

Comment: yea i tried. Doesnt work as well..